# Can not get all el-tab-pane of el-tabs

Tags: javascript, user-interface, element-plus

exist 9 children and can print 9 children but only can get 8 of them

dom is

```
  <el-tabs ref="tabs" v-model="activeName" type="card" @tab-remove="removeTab">
      <el-tab-pane
        v-for="item in dossierInfo.checkTables"
        :key="getCheckName(item.tabNo)"
        :label="getCheckLabel(item.tabNo)"
        :name="getCheckName(item.tabNo)"
        v-show="item.isDelete !== '1'"
        closable
      >
        <checkTableVue
          :formData="item"
          :appendix="dossierInfo.checkAppendixs"
          :tuDicts="tableUnitDict"
          :etDicts="eventTypeDict"
          :utDicts="underTakerDict"
          ref="checkTableVs"
        ></checkTableVue>
      </el-tab-pane>
      <el-tab-pane
        v-for="item in dossierInfo.checkAppendixs"
        :key="getAppendixName(item.tabNo)"
        :label="getAppendixLabel(item.tabNo)"
        :name="getAppendixName(item.tabNo)"
        v-show="item.isDelete !== '1'"
        closable
      >
        <appendix-vue
          ref="checkAppendixsVs"
          :formData="item"
          :appendix="dossierInfo.checkAppendixs"
          :tuDicts="tableUnitDict"
        >
        </appendix-vue>
      </el-tab-pane>
      <el-tab-pane
        v-for="item in dossierInfo.leadSources"
        :key="getSourceName(item.tabNo)"
        :label="getSourceLabel(item.tabNo)"
        :name="getSourceName(item.tabNo)"
        v-show="item.isDelete !== '1'"
        closable
      >
        <lead-source-vue :formData="item"></lead-source-vue>
      </el-tab-pane>
    </el-tabs>
```

js code is

```
  mounted() {
    this.getAllTabNames()
  },
  methods: {
    getAllTabNames() {
      const tabsRef = this.$refs.tabs;
      const tabPanesRef = tabsRef.$children;
      console.log('tabPanesRef')
      console.log(tabPanesRef)
      const allProperties = tabPanesRef.map(item=> item)
      console.log('allProperties')
      console.log(allProperties)
    },
    }
```

answer is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Sfio.png)
because the fist item is el-tab's chekMessage;so I can't get all Object;

```
const tabNames = tabPanesRef.map(pane =\> pane.name);

for(let i=0;i\<tabPanesRef.length;i++){
console.log(tabPanesRef\[i+1\])
}

const allProperties = [...Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj), ...Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj)];
```

all of them can not get the hide Object`your text`

because the fist item is el-tab's chekMessage;so I can't get all Object;why i want get all Object
because the `<checkTableVue>` and the '  `will always show even if not choose them
but click they once and  clik other ,this bug is fixed;so I want to click all of them in Mounted;but because the bug of this question show ,I can not get all name of them

Comment: <el-tab-pane
        v-for="item in dossierInfo.checkTables"
        :key="getCheckName(item.tabNo)"
        :label="getCheckLabel(item.tabNo)"
        :name="getCheckName(item.tabNo)"
        v-if="item.isDelete !== '1'"
        closable
      >  use the v-if I solve my problem，and I not solve the problem  this question show